# fopen fails in C if slash '/' is put before directory's name

Tags: c, linux, windows, fopen

If I open a file in C in any of the following ways, then `fopen` works fine.

```
fopen("file.txt", "w");
fopen("/file.txt", "w");
fopen("dir/file.txt", "w");
```

If I put a slash '/' (or '\' in case of Windows) before directory's name as follows, then `fopen` fails (returns NULL).

```
fopen("/dir/file.txt", "w");
```

It happens both on Windows (MSVC) and Linux. What is the reason of it? Should I expunge starting slash '/'?

Comment: You do understand the concept of paths? Especially the difference between an *absolute* path and a *relative* path?

Comment: Test the paths you're trying to use with "ls" or "dir" in a shell and you'll soon see where your mistake is

Comment: file.txt == file.txt int the current directory. /file.txt == file.txt in the system root directory. They're clearly not the same.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude awww.... I realized it after posting the question and trying it in a simple C file on Linux. I was initially considering it in Windows perspective only. Why is it failing on Windows though?

Comment: I would guess that the `\ ` character in your path string is being interpreted by the C compiler as an escape. To get a literal `\ ` you probably need `\\ `

Comment: The Windows file API supports "/" as a path separator, in which case "/file.txt" is in the root directory of the current drive or UNC share, which is determined by the process working directory. If that happens to be the system drive (usually C:), then by default only an administrator or system process that's running at high or system integrity level can create a file in the root directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add "." infront of the "/"

ex : `fopen("./dir/file.txt", "w");`

if you start with "/" it will start from the root directory. That is the reason fopens returns null

Comment: Don't do this. Current folder can be anything, and it's a common mistake to assume that it will point to application's directory.

Comment: Is there ever any reason to use `./dir` rather than just `dir` ?

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs I just answered how user can go to that file (in subfolder) from the current folder.

Comment: @Ran94 thanks! i came to this fix as well after reading comments above (and getting -1 vote on questions, which seems quite unfair. no?). any idea what this root path thing causing error on Windows?